# How to center an image of the fixed size container and place the fixed size download button on the left bottom corner of the same image?

Tags: html, css

**In action:**
http://jsfiddle.net/paulius_m/1xq2gn9s/4/

**In details:**

- I have a big container for group of pictures.
- In that container, I have 100x100 px containers floating to the left one beside another.
- In each of those containers I have two images surrounded by anchor tags (both looks close to like that: `<a href="/action1"><img src="/thumbnail.jpg" /></a><a href="/action2"><img src="download_button.jpg" /></a>`).
- The first image/link is the thumbnail. The size of the thumbnail could vary, but will never exceed 100px in height and 100px in width. This is know from the server side. Basically, link of the thumbnail is for invoking a lightbox feature (I am skipping describing lightbox feature here, just know it is).
- The second image/link is kind of download button. The button is always 20x20px. This is for downloading the biggest version of the same picture.
- The thumbnail must be in the middle/center of floating 100x100 px div.
- The download button (a/img tags) must be in the left bottom corner of the thumbnail.

**The problem:**

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to align the main image inside of middle/center of the 100x100 container and place the 20x20 download button on the left bottom corner of the image. The best version of what I have achieved so far could be seen in the jsfiddle link mentioned above.

**Edit:**
- The download button must always be on top of the image.

**Markup (same as in jsfiddle link):** 
**(HTML)**

```
<div class="images">
    <div class="image_container_outer">
        <div class="image_container_inner">
            <a href="http://lorempixel.com/100/67/" class="uploaded_image">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/67/" class="uploaded_image">
            </a>
            <a href="bigger_image.png" download="bigger_image.png" class="download_button">
                <img src="http://goo.gl/vEUcp6" class="download_button">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="image_container_outer">
        <div class="image_container_inner">
            <a href="http://lorempixel.com/100/67/" class="uploaded_image">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/67/" class="uploaded_image">
            </a>
            <a href="bigger_image.png" download="bigger_image.png" class="download_button">
                <img src="http://goo.gl/vEUcp6" class="download_button">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="image_container_outer">
        <div class="image_container_inner">
            <a href="http://lorempixel.com/60/100/" class="uploaded_image">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/60/100/" class="uploaded_image">
            </a>
            <a href="bigger_image.png" download="bigger_image.png" class="download_button">
                <img src="http://goo.gl/vEUcp6" class="download_button">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="image_container_outer">
        <div class="image_container_inner">
            <a href="http://lorempixel.com/100/67/" class="uploaded_image">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/67/" class="uploaded_image">
            </a>
            <a href="bigger_image.png" download="bigger_image.png" class="download_button">
                <img src="http://goo.gl/vEUcp6" class="download_button">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <span class="clear_left"></span>
</div>
```

**(CSS)**

```
.image_container_outer {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 105px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #ffff00;
}


.image_container_inner {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #999;
}

a.uploaded_image {
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

img.uploaded_image {
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 2px 0;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 50px -6px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}


a.download_button {
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

img.download_button {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: added a fix for the download button to be on top of the image, see answer edit

Comment: Can you add extra markup?

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x9Lxpj8p/) to explain how this works.**
**And here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1xq2gn9s/5/) from  your code**

To place something to absolute center use css like so:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
margin:auto;
```

and to place in the bottom left corner use css like:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
```

And to make the button on top of the image you can use:

```
z-index: 9999;
```

Comment: I will look closer in a few minutes. However, I see the problem in the solution of yours - the download button sticks to the left bottom of the gray container instead of sticking to the left bottom of the image. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @paulius Fixing that is easy, just place the download div inside the image div like so : http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/x9Lxpj8p/1/

Answer (score 0):

In your div create figure element, and then figcaption, this figcaption always on the bottom left side. in this figcaption create your button. may be its helpful.

```
<figure>
<img src="abcsd" alt="dsaer" width="304" height="228">
<figcaption>Your Button</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Nice choice. Never thought about using figure instead of div... Thanks for sharing. However, the default alignment of figure and figcaption elements are not so useful in my case. I would have to change the default alignment anyway... I think that there is no big difference on what element to use: figure or div. Of course, figure is more about HTML5 and semantics, but probably less about older browsers compatibility.